# Proper way to import a package

Tags: go

Being new to Go this is the way I'm currently importing a package that I created.  As an example:

folder path: loader\types

filename: types.go

```
package types

func SomeVal() string {
   return "ABC"
}
```

folder path: loader

filename: main.go

```
package main

import (
   "loader/types
)
func main() {

  fmt.PrintLn(SomeVal())
}
```

My question is I create another application name tester and want to reuse the types.go code, I would have to do the following

folder path: tester\types

filename: types.go

```
package types

func SomeVal() string {
   return "ABC"
}
```

folder path: tester

filename: main.go

```
package main

import (
   "tester/types"
)

func main() {

  fmt.PrintLn(SomeVal())
}
```

Is there a way to avoid calling the root folder "tester" or "loader" in the import from the main.go files?  The issue I'm facing is that I have another package

folder path: loader\view
filename: view.go

```
package view

import (
  "loader/types"
)

func AnotherValue() string {
   return SomeVal()
}
```

So if I decide to use both loader/types and loader/view in another project, I would have to change the root folder when importing.

Again I'm new to Go so I could be looking at it incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: Follow the tutorial [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code).  The tutorial shows how to import packages from your own module and other modules.

Comment: Thanks that was a good starting point along side https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module helped clear everything up

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your modules (`loader`) which contains `types` and `view` packages in other project (e.g. in other repositories), you would need to transform `loader` into a reusable module/library. Go makes use of Git for this.

This involves creating a go.mod file to indicate that this project is a valid Go module. As you said, https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module is a good starting point.

Usually, you can put this module in your repository, or in github, and so the module name should be the Git repo path, e.g. `gihub.com/adviner/loader`, something that you would put on top of your go.mod file.

`go.mod` in `loader` project:

```
module github.com/adviner/loader

go 1.19
```

If this module is hosted in public repo like github, Go will be able to retrieve it later. If you host it in a private repository that requires authentication to download, read more about using the `GOPRIVATE` environment variable from https://go.dev/ref/mod#environment-variables. Another approach is to just store this module in your local directory and use `replace` when using this module from another project.

It is a best practice that a Go project always have a go.mod file. So when you create a new project, let's say `projecta`, you might have a go.mod like this:

```
module github.com/adviner/projecta

go 1.19

require (
  github.com/adviner/loader v1.0.0
)

replace (
  github.com/adviner/loader => ../path/to/loader
)
```

We can use `replace` to replace the module with a local path so Go does not try to look for the module in github.com. This is not meant to be a permanent solution though. Usually you can just put your library in github or other private repository and remove the `replace` statement so you can work on the same project without having to transfer the `loader` module from one device to another.

PS. `v1.0.0` here is the version that is tagged in your `loader` module. It is usually a tag that is added in your Git commit. If you don't have any Git tag in the commit you can use the commit ID.

PS. When naming your module `github.com/adviner/loader`, importing packages inside `loader` should now be done like so (even in the loader project itself): `import github.com/adviner/loader/view` and no longer `loader/view`.

Reference to go.mod and Go module system can be found here: https://go.dev/ref/mod